# Python - selenium having trouble clicking on button due to footer

Tags: python, selenium, click

I am having some trouble with the following website (http://www.gamecocksonline.com/sports/m-basebl/sched/scar-m-basebl-sched.html) when it comes to clicking on one of the buttons titled 'More'. The following error is returned to the screen, and I am interpreting it as the footer is currently hovering over the button as the reason for selenium not being able to click on the correct element. Are there any ideas for a workaround here (relatively new to selenium, but I am using it to navigate to certain pages for which I feed the information to BeautifulSoup)?

```
Element <a href="#" class="sch-view-more">...</a> is not clickable at point (1172, 927). Other element would receive the click: <div id="sticky-footer-wrap">...</div>
```

Is there a reliable way to alleviate this issue via scrolling the webpage?

To answer some of the comments: The "More" links I am interested in clicking on are the ones for which there is not a GameTracker link available for that game.

CODE THUS FAR:

```
header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}
schedule = 'http://www.gamecocksonline.com/sports/m-basebl/sched/scar-m-basebl-sched.html'
url  = requests.get(schedule, headers = header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

events = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'event-listing'})
more = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'sch-view-more'})
status = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'sch-col-4'})
for idx, (i, j, k) in enumerate(zip(events, more, status)):
    if 'class="sch-gt"' in str(i):
        print(i.find('a', {'class': 'sch-gt'}).get('href'))
        # gametracker(i.find('a', {'class': 'sch-gt'}).get('href'))
    elif k.text!='Cancelled' and k.text!='Postponed':
        os.chdir('C:\Spray Charts')
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        driver.get(schedule)
        python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='sch-view-more']")[idx]
        python_button.click()
```

Comment: Your code that you are using?

Comment: I think there are 67 instances of `More` on the [URL](http://www.gamecocksonline.com/sports/m-basebl/sched/scar-m-basebl-sched.html). Which `More` are you trying to identify?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response, the code has been updated to answer your questions.